# mongoose .skip() based on parameter value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to implement pagination with mongoose for a mongoDB collection.
The `console.log(req.params.start);` correctly outputs the start value. However, the query does not start at this value — it starts from the beginning, regardless of the value.

If I change `req.params.start` to a non variable number, `2`, for example — it correctly skips 2 records.

```js
sampleRoute.route('/collection/:start').get((req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.start);

  MyModel.find()
      .skip(req.params.start)
      .limit(2)
      .exec(function (err, doc) {
          if(err) { res.status(500).json(err); return; };
          res.status(200).json(doc);
      });
})
```

How can I successfully skip using a variable? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `req.params.start` is passed as a string, I needed to convert it to Number:

```js
.skip(Number(req.params.start))
```